# An unexpected error from VBA error handler

Tags: excel, vba

Though it is not a decent way to use GOTO clause, just out of curiosity, i would like to ask why the third last statement using GOTO clause fails to work in the procedure below.

The sub procedure calculates the square root of a positive number. If a negative number is given, an error control session will take effect asking if the user would re-implement the sub again. I first entered -1, it prompt an inquiry to ask "Would you like to try again? "; later entered -2, an unexpected error occurs. [click for the picture of the unexpected error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrrK2.png). If I replace GOTO with "resume" or calling the sub itself, no unexpected error occurs.

One interpretation is "because the original error condition was not cleared". (John Walkenbach). Could someone offer some further elaboration regarding this?

```
Sub enterSqrt3()
    Dim pos_num As Variant, ans As Double, decision As Variant

TryAgain:
    On Error GoTo errHandle
    pos_num = InputBox("Please input a positive number. ")
    If pos_num = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        ans = Sqr(pos_num)
        MsgBox "The answer is " & ans
        Exit Sub
    End If

errHandle:
    decision = MsgBox("Would you like to try again? ", vbYesNo)
    If decision = vbYes Then
'        Resume TryAgain   ' it works
'        Call enterSqrt3   ' it works
         GoTo TryAgain     ' it does not work after input the second     
                           ' negative input.
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: As mentioned, you didn't clear the active exception - see http://excelmatters.com/2015/03/17/on-error-wtf/

Comment: You need to add `On Erroro Goto -1`, see [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/#On_Error_Goto_-1) for an explanation.

Comment: @Rory dose it mean that the first exception is still active so that when new error takes place, the second error do not trigger the exception handler?

Comment: Yes. And if you find yourself using `On Error Goto -1` you need to stop and have a long hard look at what you're doing. ;)

Comment: Just have a look on the examples in the link provided. @Rory: Yes, using `On Error Goto -1` is certainly not recommended

Comment: Also add the error handler,everything from `errHandle:`,  outside the main body of the procedure.  Place `Exit Sub` just before `errHandle` rather than within the `IF` code block.